# Convert int to char then push back to vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

i'm having an issue converting an int into a char. Code looks like :

```
 int main {
  int i = 10;
  char c[80];
  std::vector<char> data; 

  sprintf(i,"%d",c);
  data.push_back(c)
}
```

But I keep getting a invalid conversion from char* to std::vector ... error. Is there an easier way to convert an integer into a character and then store it inside a vector that holds chars? Because of an earlier task I need to first bring in the value as an int and I need to bring that integer 10 into the vector as '10'.

Comment: your variable c is not a char its, a char array, your vector data contains of chars, if you want to add a char to the vector it works like this: `data.push_back('a');`

Comment: “data” is vector of char, not char* . You are trying to pass char instead of char* to push_back. In order to store char* in the vector, use vector<char*>. But be careful about storing the pointers of local variables. In your case, c is local, it will be deleted when the scope is finished.

Comment: `c` is a raw array of `char` so its type is `char*` since it points to the first element to that array. So, you can only push back elements of that array, like`c[0]` into that vector. Maybe you want to use `std::string` instead?

Comment: Where are `text` and `f` declared?

Comment: A char and string are not the same thing. Do you really want a vector of chars, or do you want a vector of strings? Without knowing which this is a hard question to answer.

Comment: Put it another way, suppose you added the number 123 to your vector, how big would the vector be? Would it be three because there are three digits in the number, or would it be one, because there is only one number. See the problem? The question you have asked is ambiguous.

Comment: To clarify I need a vector<char> that stores 10 like '1','0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters it seems there is a typo

```
sprintf(text,"%d",f);
```

You nean

```
sprintf( c ,"%d", i );
```

The value type of this vector

```
std::vector<char> data;
```

is `char`. So in the member function push you have to supply an expression that has the type `char`. However in this call

```
data.push_back(c);
```

you supplied an object of an array type

```
char c[80];
```

If you want to store in the vector a character representation of a number as separate characters then you can write for example

```
size_t n = strlen( c );
data.reserve( n );
data.assign( c, c + n );
```

Or you could declare the vector initializing it by the representation of the number like

```
std::vector<char> data( c, c + n );
```

If you want to store the whole number as one element of the vector then you should declare the vector like

```
std::vector<std::string> data( 1, std::to_string( i ) );
```

Comment: This worked and gave me insight into some of the stuff I didn't understand about how c++ stores stuff into vectors. Thank you.